# how to initialize a multidimensional array--matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Given two numbers: `M, N`, how to create a matrix: `res = MxMxMxMxM...xM`, where `ndims(res) == N`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the Array `[M,M,M...]` and pass it:

```
nan(repmat(M,1,N))
```